# xcopy: move files instead of copy?

Tags: windows-7, xcopy

I would like to use `xcopy` to move, not copy files across a network with the Verify flag. I could not find a switch on xcopy to move files, is there an `xmove` I can use that has `verify`?

At the moment I am using `xcopy /D /V` but need to get rid of the files at the source *only* when it is verified a file was successfully copied to the destination.

Comment: You should be aware that even using `/v` does not guarantee that a file has been correctly written: disc and OS caches mean that a file in a write cache will be retrieved from there before it has been committed successfully. The only safe option is to make a copy and schedule a verify and delete at a future time. Heuristically I would say that 5 minutes would be enough, but there is no hard and fast rule: it depends on the disc activity and the size of the caches (I speak as one who has encountered cached write failures).

Answer (score 12):

You should check out `robocopy`, it is much more powerful than `xcopy`. You can easily move files with `/MOV` or `/MOVE`.

**To move files only (delete from source after copying)**

```
robocopy from_folder to_folder files_to_copy /MOV
```

**To move files and directories (delete from source after copying)**

```
robocopy from_folder to_folder files_to_copy /MOVE
```

http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: Robocopy does not have a `verify` as far as I can see.

Comment: @JBurace If you look at the link I posted it states: `/MOVE : Move files and dirs (delete from source after copying)`. If it doesn't copy, it won't remove the source.

Comment: What happens if it gets moved, but the filesize doesn't match? This is why I need to do a `verify`. I don't see anything in the robocopy info that it actually verifies the two filesizes to ensure it wasn't just moved but moved correctly.

Comment: @JBurace I don't think it works like that. If it doesn't copy all of the file, then it will act as if nothing copied at all, and therefore will not remove the source.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a batch file to run your `Xcopy` command with the verify, followed by a check of the error level returned by Xcopy to determine if the files copied successfully or not.  If they did, delete the source.

From the [Xcopy documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx):

```
Exit
code  Description
====  ===========
  0   Files were copied without error.
  1   No files were found to copy.
  2   The user pressed CTRL+C to terminate xcopy.
  4   Initialization error occurred. There is not
      enough memory or disk space, or you entered
      an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on
      the command line.
  5   Disk write error occurred.
```

Example batch:

```
Rem Attempt file copy...
xcopy /D /V %1 %2

Rem Check result code and if it was successful (0), delete the source.
if errorlevel 0 (
    echo Copy completed successfully
    del /Q %1
    exit /B
)

Rem Not Errorlevel 0...
echo Copy failed for some reason.
```

Comment: Does `errorlevel` still work if I'm doing: `dir args && xcopy args >> logfile.txt`? Or will `errorlevel` be a result of `dir`?

Comment: It will contain the result of the last command run. You can test it with a simple batch file as such: http://pastebin.com/6GwNA7MP

Comment: `if errorlevel 0` ALWAYS triggers.  Because it is really checking for `if errorlevel >= 0` so you should instead check the error case `if errorlevel 1 ( ... failure case ... ) else ( ... success case ... )`. Or, if you prefer the style `if not errorlevel 0 (... success case ... )` Or, if you prefer the style `if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( ... success case ... )`

Comment: Of course this would be far less efficient (move is super cheap in the same hard drive)...